# Can Genji deflect when using Dragonblade?

Tags: overwatch

I'm curious as to whether deflect works during Genji's ultimate. He seems to be able to use the ability, but does it still work as normal?

Comment: Downvotes are because this is easily found in the general reference: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji#Dragonblade

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he can. Anyone can easily test this by using the Testing Range.

Comment: so he had a blade then he pull out other deflecting blades?

Comment: @JimThio He deflects using his Dragonblade but I don't see how that is relevant to anything given I just told you how you can test it yourself.

Comment: @JimThio He only has one sword which he uses to deflect and for Dragonblade. If you watch a Genji deflect he takes the sword off his back, same for dragonblade, but while using dragonblade he already has the sword out. It makes no difference mechanically when you use deflect.

Comment: he uses 2 sword when deflecting

Comment: It doesn't matter what blade he uses, it's a video game. He could magically manifest a third blade, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: Genji has 2 swords by the way. He seems to be using the short one while deflecting and the long one to chop enemies to pieces. So how can changes blade in the middle of dragon blade is a bit confusing. I know it's a video game. But there is usually some in game explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Also, he can use Swift Strike as well while his Dragonblade is up.

On a side note, if you cast your Deflect as your Dragonblade's duration is ending, the sheathing animation at the end of the Dragonblade's duration will cancel a part of Deflect's duration, as such avoid activating Deflect when your Dragonblade is about to end.